# Django form fields and button appear not in order

Tags: html, django, forms

This is the code of the HTML page in which the form will be displayed:

```
    <body>
        <h1>Add a Category</h1>

        <form id="category_form" method="post" action="/rango/add_category/">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Category" />
        </form>
    </body>
```

**This is how the form is getting displayed:**
[image: Output]

What am I missing in the code?
I'm following  [the TWD Tutorial](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/forms.html#creating-modelform-classes)

**Output according to the tutorial:**

[image: Desired output]

Comment: You haven't done any mistake? Are to trying to get button in new line?

Comment: I'm actually  following along the steps.
But curious about why I'm not getting the output as in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Inputs and buttons are inline elements so they appear in the same row.  Resize the browser window and this button will be moved to the next row like any other text element.

If you want to place the button under the inputs regardless of the window width then put the button into the block element like `<div>` or `<p>`:

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Category" />
</div>
```